# Is there a way to get dynamic data into a Slider Revolution slide from a PHP script?

Tags: plugins

I have a PHP class that I'm using to make requests to an external API for data like view/follower counts.

I want to show a couple pieces of that data on my homepage in a Slider Revolution slide.

There aren't any default layers that I can put in to execute PHP code or anything like that that I have found. I know that there is a custom JS area, where I could potentially make an AJAX request to a script that instantiates the class and returns data from it.

But I'm not sure how I would implement that data within the slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was easier than I thought, didn't know that you could [execute shortcodes in the text/html block](https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/text-html-icons/).

```
function twitch_api_client_views_shortcode() {
    $twitch = twitch_api_client();
    return $twitch->getViewCount();
}
add_shortcode( 'twitch-views', 'twitch_api_client_views_shortcode' );
```

And then `[twitch-views]` in Slider Revolution `text/html` layer.